How to present the relation between two KPIs
The case is for a logistics company. We are trying to show our users their current emissions and how much emissions they can save/avoid/reduce by choosing more sustainable routing options. On our dashboard we would like to show users a KPI for this, so they can more easily keep track and communicate with their stakeholders. For instance "Boss, we can reduce 40% of our emissions if we choose more sustainable routes on 25% of our routes. 75% of our routes are already fine"
NB: we have other graphs to identify the actual hotspots. As it could be that only 2 routes are responsible for that 40% of avoidable emissions.
The challenge

Make the relation understood between projected emissions and
avoidable emissions on the one hand and the percentage of routes that
have more sustainable alternatives on the other.
Should fit on a relatively small component.

What I tried so far


Your question almost reads as a design request or review but that is not what this site is for. The only advise I can give is to focus on the story, less on the details. From the examples you posted I see that there is a lot of attention to the aesthetics. But only aesthetics without a story don't have much purpose. To give an idea, I believe this tells the story although it doesn't look that good.

I chose for vertical bars because it better projects amounts or volumes. Horizontal bars are better to project time or distance.

Thanks for your advice, and your suggestion!
I like the consistency in labelling "potential" for both.
